# How to identify requesting keycloak user in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, keycloak

I'm pretty new to the world of authentication / keycloak, and after reading the keycloak doc I still can't wrap my head around the following situation.
Let's assume there's an existing web-application with keycloak as IAM.
Now, I need to implement a Flask/dash application which provides a service with business client specific data and dedicated API endpoints for all the business clients. Let's say the base URL is `website.com/myapp/`
Each business client has users in keycloak and some, not all, should access the data at the according endpoint,  `website.com/myapp/client1/` 
`user_1` can view `/client1/`, `user_2` and `user_3` can view `/client2/`
That means I have to hardcode somewhere (database?) which user belongs to a client endpoint, correct?
In keycloak I've setup a client (myapp) with `service accounts enabled`
I gave the client a role `view`
I gave a user the role `view`
With the client_id and client_secret I can obtain the access_token and make all the known requests via the keycloak API.
The API routes in Flask/dash have a decorator function to check if the user is logged in and has the general view permission for `myapp`.
This works fine, but the problem is I need to pass the `user_id` to check if the keycloak session is active or not.
How do I check for the logged in user_id or user_name who wants to access `/myapp/` so that I can validate the view permission and match to the dedicated Flask route?

authentication:

```
def authentication(user_id):


    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token'

    payload = 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=payload, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret))
    
    token = json.loads(response.text)


    return get_client_roles(token['access_token']), get_sessions(token['access_token'], user_id)


def get_sessions(token, user_id):

    
    url = f'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/users/{user_id}/sessions'

    payload = {}
    headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token }
    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    sessions = json.loads(response.text)

    return sessions

def get_client_roles(token):

    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/clients/'+id+'/roles/view/users'

    payload = {}
    headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token }
    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    client_roles = json.loads(response.text)

    return client_roles
```

With that I can check if user_x is logged in and has role `view` for `myapp`

But unfortunately I need to hardcode the user_id in my Flask/dash file:

excerption from Flask/dash:

```
dash_app1 = dash.Dash(server = app, name = 'Dashboard client1', url_base_pathname='/client1/')
dash_app2 = dash.Dash(server = app, name = 'Dashboard client2', url_base_pathname='/client2/')
...

user_id = 'dsdgbc-fd68-41c3-b6d-34fds343436aa75' # how to retrieve and not hardcode?

@app.route("/client1/", endpoint='route1')
@login_required
def render_dashboard():
    return redirect('/client1/')
```

The user_id is the parameter in authentication(user_id) in the decorator function

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the OIDC protocol and try to understand how it works.
Use a library like [flask-oidc](https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or something similar and do not use the admin API. It is not intended for what you want to achive.

Comment: Thank you for the tipp! I'll look into flask-oicd